# Detecting the Location your cocoa swift application is running from

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying but unable to find out if there is a way using swift to detect the path and name of the .app file that is running

ie if my app is selfupdater.app and its stored in ~username/applications

how can i get this information when selfupdater.app is launched as a string variable in swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called your main bundle folder.

**Swift 3 or later**

```
extension URL {
    var parentDirectory: URL? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.parentDirectoryURLKey]))?.parentDirectory
    }
}
```

---

```
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL

if let path = bundleURL.parentDirectory?.path {
    print(path)
}
```