# How can I find out where is my App located using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Im making Cocoa app and there is no problem when building app with xcode but when I use compiled app the path is /.
I turned of the sandbox BTW.

```
@IBAction func showMeCurrentDIrector(_ sender: Any) {
        let fileManger=FileManager.default  
        lblShow.stringValue = fileManger.currentDirectoryPath.description
        print(type(of: fileManger.currentDirectoryPath.description))
        print(fileManger.currentDirectoryPath.description)
    }
```

[image: Xcode compiled vs Final App]

Comment: Where does the path come from?  And for what purpose are you using the description property?

Comment: When an app is launched, this property is initially set to the app’s current working directory. If the current working directory is not accessible for any reason, the value of this property is nil. You can change the value of this property by calling the changeCurrentDirectoryPath(_:) method.

Comment: Where is your App located?

Comment: @ElTomato I agree that using the description property is pointless (currentDirectoryPath is a String) but it won't make any difference if he doesn't.

Comment: @ElTomato I just want that where ever I put the app,It can find out its location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27994948/2303865 updated to Swift 4

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks pal.Its working